# How to use the SQlite last_insert_row() in a secondary query in flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I'm working on a offline-first flutter application that updates its records online to a MySQL database for a desktop web access and multi user access. My flutter application creates a new To-Do item for a To-Do List module and saves it locally to SQLITE. It then sends this new record to my online server via HTTP POST where it inserts this new record to the MYSQL database online and returns its recently created ID for the record. Then Flutter updates the record it created locally on SQLITE to save the "online_todo_id".

My problem: How do I write the syntax in flutter to set a new variable to the local SQLITE last_insert_rowid()?

```
var result = await db.insert(todoTABLE, todo.toDatabaseJson()); //Insert local record SQLITE

//......Http Post REST API to server, returns online_todo_id....
todo.online_todo_id=online_todo_id;// Here I set the new value in the todo object thats going to be updated.
var result2 =  await db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS id");
var last_insert_rowid= last_insert_rowid(); //****--HELP HERE--****\\
var result2 = await db.update(todoTABLE, todo.toDatabaseJson(),
          where: "todo_id = ?", whereArgs: [last_insert_rowid]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably late for you,
but for anyone else who comes across this,
sqflite's common package returns the last insert rowId as a result of the db.insert statement.

So basically to get the rowId of an insert statement, you just need to:

```
var last_insert_rowId = await db.insert(todoTABLE, todo.toDatabaseJson());
```